# Bulkify Apex Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest

Tags: apex, bulkification, approval-process

I have an apex class that submits opportunities for approval if they are over a certain threshold. This works great when processing small batches, but when trying to submit larger batches it fails with "Too many DML Statements".

I haven't been able to find anything that says I can process a list of records with the [Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_process.htm) class - so am doing it within a for loop. I tried swapping to a @future class for the Approval, but that has a limit of 50 @future calls as well.

Looking to bulkify this or identify an alternative option.

```
for(Opportunity o :lstOppty){
    String recordtypename = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosById().get(o.recordtypeid).getname();
    if(o.BSO_Audit_Flag__c && o.Last_Review_Date__c == null && opptyRTaudit.contains(recordtypename) && Approval.isLocked(o.id) == false){
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req.setComments('Opportunity was submitted for approval.');
        req.setObjectId(o.Id);
        try{
            Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req);
            System.debug('Submitted for approval successfully: '+result.isSuccess());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('Submitted for approval failed. This usually means the BSO Alignment or Country on User profile is not set correctly. Error Message: = ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the [`Approval.process`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_approval.htm) method has a signature which accepts a `List<Approval.ProcessRequest>`:

> public static Approval.ProcessResult [] process(Approval.ProcessRequest[] approvalRequests)